# Loop this Excel Macro?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have this code below, and basically I want to able to make it do a whole range of cells from `R16` to `R200` and `Range("G16").Select` to `G200`.

i.e. when it changes to R17 then G16 becomes 17, when R18 then G18 etc.

So the whole function runs changing `R2` to `R3` and `G2` to `G3`, starts again and changes `R3` to `R4`, `G3` to `G4`, etc.

```
Sub Search()

Range("H2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(R16C6,RC[4])),RC[2],"""")" ' Edit RXX value
Range("H2").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("H2:H385")
Range("H2:H385").Select
Range("G16").Select ' Edit GXX value
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SpecialConcatenate(C[1])"
Range("G11").Select
Application.Run "Test.xlsm!CopyPaste"
Range("H2").Select

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Sub Search2()

    With Range("h2:h385")
        .FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(R[14]C6,RC[4])),RC[2],"""")"
    End With

    Range("G16").FormulaR1C1 = "=SpecialConcatenate(C[1])"
    Application.Run "Test.xlsm!CopyPaste"

End Sub
```

If you put the R number in brackets, it makes it relative to whatever cell you're in.  So R[14] will point to row 16 when you're in row 2 and it will point to row 214 when you're in row 200.

Comment: hi thanks for the response :) - does this also increase the range of G ? i.e. so as changes from h2 to h3, G changes from g2 to g3 ? the repeats [h4, g4, / h5, g6 etc ]

Comment: Yes.  R[14]C6 means to go 14 rows down in column G.  The C6 always points to column G regardless of the current column (because it doesn't use brackets).  The R[14] changes as the row changes.  RC[4] means stay on the same row and go 4 columns to the right.  In this one, both the row and column are relative to the active cell.